# Change Apache Flink binding address in local mode

Tags: apache-flink

Flink (or some of its services) listens on three random TCP ports during the [local](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/local_execution.html#local-environment) execution, e.g., 39951, 41009 and 42849.

The sockets listens on `0.0.0.0` and since I need to run some long-running tests on an Internet-facing machine I was wondering how to make them listen on `localhost` instead or if there is anything else I can do to improve the security in this scenario.

Here's what I tried (with little luck):

```
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.setString("taskmanager.host", "127.0.0.1");
cconfig.setString("rest.bind-address", "127.0.0.1"); // OK
config.setString("jobmanager.rpc.address", "127.0.0.1");
StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.createLocalEnvironment(StreamExecutionEnvironment.getDefaultLocalParallelism(), config);
```

Only the `rest.bind-address` configuration actually changes the
binding address of one of those ports. Are there other parameters that
I'm not aware of or this is not the right approach in local mode?

---

**Update:** upstream [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-15154).

Comment: Have you tried setting these config options? https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.9/ops/config.html#taskmanager-host, https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.9/ops/config.html#rest-bind-address, https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.9/ops/config.html#jobmanager-rpc-address ?

Comment: It's not clear where should I put those in my scenario.

Comment: I've updated the question with what I tried.

Comment: You used some keys incorrectly as they contain dashes in places where they should use periods; it is `rest.bind-address` and `jobmanager.rpc.address`

Comment: Whoops, right, I was copying from the URL directly... This fixed the problem with one socket only: `rest.bind-address`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting these config options?

```
conf/flink-conf.yaml

jobmanager.bind-host

taskmanager.bind-host
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what these config options do and how they could help the OP.